# llamar desde c# a un procedimiento almacenado de oracle, si funciona con un provedor y no con otro

Tags: c#, oracle, odac

quien me ayuda con este problema, tenia un sistema en .net 1.1 (VS2003) que se conectaba con el provedor `Provider=MSDAORA.1`, todo esto corría en un WS2003 a la perfección, se decidió migrar esta solución a VS2008 y que corra sobre WS2012R2, como este Windows no tiene x86 ya no puedo usar dicho proveedor así que cambiamos la cadena de conexión a utilizar es proveedor `Provider=ORAOLEDB.ORACLE`, ahora no encontramos en pruebas y se llama a un SP de la siguiente manera:

```
        initializar_conn()

        comando = New OleDbCommand("BI.BI_Obtiene_ComFir_Trx", conn)
        comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        Dim p_cod_ope As OleDbParameter = comando.Parameters.Add("pCodOpe", OleDbType.VarChar, 5)
        p_cod_ope.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        p_cod_ope.Value = CodOpe 'Codigo Operacion

        Dim p_trx As OleDbParameter = comando.Parameters.Add("pCodTrx", OleDbType.VarChar, 20)
        p_trx.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        p_trx.Value = CodTrx 'Codigo Transaccion

        Dim p_confir As OleDbParameter = comando.Parameters.Add("pConFir", OleDbType.VarChar, 50)
        p_confir.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

        comando.ExecuteNonQuery()

        vConFir = Convert.ToString(p_confir.Value).Trim
```

El punto es que con el antiguo proveedor, el p_confirm.value me devolvía el dato que retorna el sp, pero con el nuevo proveedor simplemente me retorna el valor de vació.

Alguien sabe a que se debe esto? o que debo modificar para que me funcione la invocación al SP con el nuevo proveedor?

Saludos cordiales a todos.

Comment: Puedes usar ODAC http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

Comment: ????? o sea? entendiste la pregunta? 1. Obvismente utilizo ODAC para conectarme, una cosa es el ODAC y otro cosa es usar unos de los varios provedores que proporciona el ODAC, mmmmm....

Comment: Si usas ODAC por que usas `OleDbCommand` y no `OracleCommand`

Answer (score 1):

Usando [ODAC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/downloads/index-101290.html), así es como trabajo con un *store procedure*:

```
Using cn As OracleConnection = Conexion.Conectar("default")
    cn.Open()
    Using cmd As OracleCommand = cn.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandText = "Prueba2.pakclientes.usp_addcliente"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("int_idcliente", OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = cliente.IdCliente
            .Add("str_ruc", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 11, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = cliente.Ruc
            .Add("str_nombre", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 80, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = cliente.Nombre
            .Add("str_razonsocial", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 100, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = cliente.RazonSocial
            .Add("str_direccion", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 100, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = cliente.Direccion
        End With
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

Y no tener que estar declarando cada parámetro que vas a usar.